# How can I idiomatically transform some text in place using elisp?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I've got some json that I'd like to process in emacs. I've found and used the elisp library to extract the desired content from the json, and I'd like to replace the json with the elisp equiivalent that I've extracted.

This is what I've written:

```
(defun extract-foo (start end)
  "Extract the foo field from a json object in the region"
  (interactive "r")
  (let ((my_json (cdr (assoc 'FOO  (json-read-from-string (buffer-substring-no-properties start end))))))
    (delete-region start end)
    (SOMETHING) 
))
```

I'm stuck at the  something.  I can't seem to find a way to write the contents of my_json to the buffer at the mark. The only way I can think of is to save the text instead to a temporary buffer, and then `(insert-buffer)` it. This seems excessive to me though.

How can I do this idiomatically in elisp?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to write back JSON partial

```
(insert (format "%s" (json-encode my-json)))
```

to write back elisp:

```
(insert (format "%s" my-json))
```

Note that your use of underscore in variable naming is contrary to convention.